# custom display format for a field

Tags: entities

I have a field "Organisation name" on the user profile. The users fills the organization he is working for when creating his profile.

On the profile display page, I would like to add a custom display to this field. When some one hovers over this field, I would like to show some information about the organization from dbpedia/wikipedia.

I would like to know how i can add a custom display to a field on the user profile. Can i do this with the Display Suite module ?

Comment: Yes you can add a custom `code_field` to programmatically create the additional information ... somehow. Whether you make an iframe, a javascript callout box or whatever is up to you. How you fetch and store that information periodically (CuRL, webservice ...), is also up to you. DS will only make the field -- not do the business logic to get to the remote data.

Comment: Yes I already worked on the logic to get the data from dbpedia. Just wondering How i can use it to display information on the field.